# Storing values in functional programming style

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have a file readstream giving me values I need to accumulate in a function which needs to return a value.

PSEUDOCODE:

```
data = [];

process(item){
 data.push(item);
 data.length > 2 && data.shift();
 if data[0] == 'ok'.. 
   return data[1];
 else 
   return something else
}

stream(item){
 process(item);
}
```

now this would be full of side effects and bad practice.
I don't know how to translate this into FP at all...

Just for practice. please.

Comment: How is `stream()` called? If its return value is ignored, you *must* use a side effect.

Comment: @Bergi 

```const fs = require('fs');
const parse = require('csv-parse');

module.exports = async (symbol, interval) => {

  const parser = parse({ delimiter: ',' });
  fs.createReadStream('./pairs/'+symbol+'.csv', 'utf8').pipe(parser); 

  parser.on('readable', (r) => { while (r = parser.read()) { ......<<< this is the "stream" function i used in my pseudocode.

```
Maybe I need something like a transducer.. but idk how to implement it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Avoid mutations, return new state instead. 
Produce output based on input only, but not on global/closured objects (or at least not on mutable closured objects).

Possible FP-ish implementation of your example:

```
function process(item, oldData) {

 const data = [...oldData];
 data.push(item);
 data.length > 2 && data.shift();
 if(data[0] == 'ok') {
   return {
        result: data[1],
      interimData: data
   };
 }
 else {
    return {
       result: return something else,
      interimData: data
   };
 }
}

function stream(item, data){
 return process(item, data);
}

var data = [];
data = stream(item1 , data).interimData;
data = stream(item2 , data).interimData;
...
const finalResult = stream(item3 , data);
```

Comment: thank you for this. I really need to wrap my head around this concept.

Comment: also please have a look at Array.reduce ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce )